# iPhone inconsistently executing javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios

I have the following link:

```
<a href='external-url' class='track' data-type='event' data-category='category'>
   Link
</a>
```

When the link is clicked, the following function is executed:

```
$('a.track').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   var type     = $(this).data("type");
   var category = $(this).data("category");

   track(type, category);
   window.location = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

The track function posts the data via ajax and stores it in a database. On desktop browsers, this is working completely. On Android, this is also working completely.

On iPhone, I'm seeing it *not* work about 10 times (the link takes me to the external site without the addition to the database), then it'll magically start working for around 10 times! Can anyone identify what the issue might be, either in my code or maybe something with iOS I'm overlooking?

Comment: what does `track()` do? Nothing suspicious about the code except for that function. Is `track()`, by any chance, an AJAX call to the server?

Comment: Yep, exactly: "The track function posts the data via ajax and stores it in a database." Would that play out differently on iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that `track()` is an asynchronous operation.

In other browsers, maybe it was just fast enough (and you just got lucky) that it did all it's tasks before `window.location` was executed. But then, this behavior is weird.

However, on the iPhone, `track()` maybe executed too slow that executing `window.location` already cancelled the operation because the page was exiting to another page. This is proper behavior for async operations. It should have acted the same on all browsers as well.

Instead of this sequential code, try using callbacks. You pass in a function that gets executed once track has done doing it's job:

```
function track(type,category,callback){
    //track operations up here and your ajax setup
    //execute callback when ajax operation replies
    if(ajaxStatus === 200){
        callback();
    }
}

//using track, we pass in parameters and the callback
//which when executed, runs the code inside it
track(type,category,function(){
    window.location  = ...;
});
```

Comment: Using a callback is definitely the right approach. It completely avoids the issue of *hoping* events happen a specific way.

Answer (score 1):

You have a race condition. You have to hope the request makes it.

When the page exits, it kills the open requests. I am surprised it would work on desktop browsers, they should have the same problem. Put it on a far off server on a slow network, I am betting they will not make it.

In the past it was easy to make it work with a while loop, but chrome/firefox killed that.

If it is an external site, open it up into a new window. Keep your site open.